# Nextjs vscode debug permission issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink...

How do I run the debugger as root or something? I read on another post it's bad to run vscode itself as root.

I tried putting sudo in the launch.json file suggested on other stack questions but it says root shouldn't be placed there. Maybe older versions?

Here is my launch file.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s",
                "action": "debugWithChrome"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```